# Audiokit AKSampler as a AKNode/AKPolyphonicNode in a separate class

Tags: swift, swiftui, audiokit

How can I separate AKSampler into a class?
For instance:

SoundEngine.swift

```swift
import AudioKit
import MySampler

final class SoundEngine : ObservableObject {
    static let shared = SoundEngine()
    let mySampler = MySampler()

    init() {
        mySampler.loadSamples('samples1')
        AudioKit.output = AKMixer(noise1, noise2, mySampler)
        try AudioKit.start()

        mySampler.play(note: 60, vel: 127)
    }
```

MySampler.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import AudioKit

class MySampler : AKPolyphonicNode {
    var mySampler1 = AKSampler()

    func play(note: MIDINoteNumber, vel: MIDIVelocity) {
        mySampler1.play(noteNumber: note, velocity: velocity)
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with both `AKNode` or `AKPolyphonicNode` like in the example above: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio’, reason: ‘required condition is false: node != nil’`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the SoundEngine.swift:

```
import AudioKit

final class SoundEngine {

    static let shared = SoundEngine()

    // Create instance variables of the MySampler objects.
    // I renamed them from noise1, noise2, and mySampler1, so that they are descriptive and clear about the intended sounds from each MySampler object.
    var kick: MySampler
    var snare: MySampler
    var hiHat: MySampler

    var drumMixer: AKMixer

    init() {

        // Instantiate MySampler objects
        kick = MySampler()
        snare = MySampler()
        hiHat = MySampler()

        // These drum samples are royalty-free from Music Radar: https://www.musicradar.com/news/drums/1000-free-drum-samples
        kick.loadSample(filePath: "CYCdh_K2room_Kick-08")
        snare.loadSample(filePath: "CYCdh_K2room_Snr-05")
        hiHat.loadSample(filePath: "CYCdh_K2room_ClHat-06")

        // Initialize the AudioKit engine settings.
        AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium
        AKSettings.enableRouteChangeHandling = true
        AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true

        do {
            try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth, .mixWithOthers])
        } catch {
            AKLog("Could not set session category.")
        }

        // Combine the samples into a mixer, so that they can be played together in a single output.
        drumMixer = AKMixer(snare, kick, hiHat)
        AudioKit.output = drumMixer

        // Start the audio engine
        try! AudioKit.start()

    }

    // MARK: Sample Playback Triggers

    // The following functions can be triggered via the button actions from the ViewController.
    internal func playKick() {
        try! kick.play(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 127, channel: 0)
    }

    internal func playSmare() {
        try! snare.play(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 127, channel: 0)
    }

    internal func playHiHat() {
        try! hiHat.play(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 127, channel: 0)
    }

}
```

For MySampler.swift:

```
import AudioKit

class MySampler: AKMIDISampler {

    internal func loadSample(filePath: String) {
        do {
            try self.loadWav(Constants.sampleDirectoryPath + filePath)
            // This will interpolate a string variable path like this: "Sounds/CYCdh_K2room_Kick-08"
        } catch {
            print("Could not locate the wav file.")
        }
    }
}
```

I also added a Constant, so that you could just provide the audio file name, and not have to include the directory path.

Constants.swift:

```
struct Constants {

    static let sampleDirectoryPath = "Sounds/"

}
```

I created a GitHub project for your reference:

https://github.com/markjeschke/AudioKitSamplerClass

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your "What am I doing wrong?" Is that you've initiated a second sampler that is part of your MySampler class that is being played, but is not connected to the signal chain. Sure, its parent is in the AKMixer, but that doesn't mean that some random property within it will be. Perhaps some other nice person will post a GitHub project of a better set up example.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, Aure!